# Azure Data Factory - replace expression in derived column transformation using Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure, etl, derived-column, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am trying to use Azure Data Factory for a Derived column transformation task one of my tasks is mentioned below,

DESCRIPTION_TEXT : UNILEVER GROUP ##### GBR

Remove trailing country code (only when it equals to country) and ##### if they exist

My code in Expression builder:

replace(ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT, COUNTRY_CODE, substring(ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT, 0, instr(ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,'#')-1))

and this is not working as I expected

(Out put is : UNILEVER GROUP ##### UNILEVER GROUP )

The Expected output is UNILEVER GROUP.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the above and able to achieve your requirement using `iif` in dataflow expression like below.

```
iif(and(greater(instr(ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,'#'),0),greater(instr(ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT, $country_code),0)), substring(ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT, 0, instr(ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT,'#')-1), ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT)
```

Here `country_code` is a parameter and I have given the values as `'GBR'`.

If the `ORIGINAL_DESCRIPTION_TEXT` column contains `'#'` and `country_code`y, then it stores the string from start to the index of `'#'`. If not, it stores the same column without any changes.

**Result:**

[image]